# Testing CIF Modification - Request JSON Not De-Serializing Correctly

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

Getting this error w/Customer/CustMod:

"Description": "Unable to successfully complete requested action.  See detail section for more information in the standard jXchange fault format.",
"MessageSource": "Service Gateway",
"Details": [
{
"Code": "225",
"Category": "Error",
"Description": "Invalid CIF number",
"Element": "CustId",
"ElementValue": "       0",
"Location": "CFCUSTMOD"
}
]
}

...however, my request header looks like this (following the SOAP object model) and I have obscured the CIF to be fictitious and removed relevant header info but it was a live CIF:

{
"CustModRq": {
"ActIntentKey": null,
"CustDetail": {
"AnnIncmAmt": "15000",
"AssetTotAmt": null,
"BirthDt": null,
"CustCrtRsnCode": null,
"Custom": null,
"CustOrgDt": null,
"CustType": null,
"Deceased": null,
"DeceasedDt": null,
"EducLvl": null,
"EmplName": null,
"EmplTitle": "jXchange Guru",
"Gender": null,
"HouseHoldName": null,
"HouseHoldNum": null,
"LastConDt": null,
"LastMainDt": null,
"NAICSCode": null,
"OccType": null,
"StdIndustCode": null
},
"CustId": "L012345",
"Dlt": null,
"MsgRqHdr": {
"AuthenProdCred": "",
"AuthenUsrCred": null,
"jXchangeHdr": {
"AuditUsrId": "Test",
"AuditWsId": "Test",
"AuthenUsrId": null,

Not sure why it won't deserialize this correctly.  I have also seen this on the customer search where your parser doesn't pick up the MaxRec value even though it's set to 100 so I cannot search.

Is there something else I'm missing or is the SOAP documentation out of date?

FYI - I'm using the Mulesoft JSON implementation but still following the SOAP object structure.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are displaying at the top is stating that the CIF is invalid meaning you are passing in an incorrect CustId. This does not indicate that there is a serialization problem with the request. We do offer sample Postman JSON payloads on our Developer Portal SOAP Documentation (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/documentation/) look for the DMZ Rest-Legacy Tests.postman_collection.

Additionally, the MaxRec for the search is found in the endpoint not passed in as a value. An example of this can be seen on our Getting Started with jXchange REST Legacy page (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/getting-started-with-jxchange-rest-legacy/). The Count= part of the endpoint is the MaxRec part of the request. Here is the endpoint from that page for your conveinence.
(https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/getting-started-with-jxchange-rest-legacy/)

Upon review we noticed that the *Srch use of the Count= as the MaxRec is not clear and will work to update the page to make that more understandable.

Comment: The CIF is 100% valid (and I've tried a few different ones).  The error indicates it's parsing it as 0 when it is clearly not a zero. So either the error displayed is not correct or the input JSON is not correct (but follows the SOAP model as indicated on the website).